# Best way for correlation analysis

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, correlation, data-analysis

I am looking for an alternative way of analysing my data which will be used for ML. I am using Matlab to implement my code. Using my code, I obtain arrays which are used to describe signals. Each array represents a new and different signal.

I have used the corrcoeff method in Matlab and it delivered what I needed. But, I need another alternative way to verify the correlation between all the signals. Is there a better way to do this which is easy to interpret?

Dumb question: is it better to compare the images of the signal generated by Matlab or to compare the arrays?

Forgive me if this sounds badly formulated but I hope it is clear.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: If you add a snippet of what your arrays look like, you might get more/better answers. Currently, it is unclear what your array looks like (shape?)

Comment: I currently don't have access to my array right now. But I can tell you it is a 50 x 12 array. 50 different data with 12 fields. All of this data will be compared to the initial data and will output a correlation coefficient.

I am now thinking how i can best graphically display these data to have a good overview of all the coefficients and group them together

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current details about your question, I'm not sure what you seek, but I will give it a try.

I assumed you already tried Pearson's coefficient. There are other metrics, which are more or less difficult to implement if not already existing in matlab.

- [Spearman's rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)
- [Coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)
- Hilbert-Schmidt independence criterion

All those will provide some insight about dependencies within your dataset.